# How do I translate 黄金鸡柳咖喱饭 (huángjīn jīliǔ gālí fàn), which means something like "gold chicken willow curry with rice"?

Tags: translation, food

I'm trying to translate the menu from one of the cafeterias on campus to help international students.  I'm stuck on this one:

[image: 黄金鸡柳咖喱饭]

> 黄金鸡柳咖喱饭
>   huángjīn jīliǔ gālí fàn

Assuming I've transcribed it correctly, it says:

- [黄金](http://dict.cn/%E9%BB%84%E9%87%91) (huángjīn) = gold
- [鸡](http://dict.cn/%E9%B8%A1) (jī) = chicken (used as an abbreviation for the meat 鸡肉)
- [柳](http://dict.cn/%E6%9F%B3) (liǔ) = willow (translation at [YouDao](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E6%9F%B3/#keyfrom=dict2.index))
- [咖喱](http://dict.cn/%E5%92%96%E5%96%B1) (gālí) = curry
- [饭](http://dict.cn/%E9%A5%AD) (fàn) = rice

So I literally translate it to:

> gold chicken willow curry with rice

I don't think this is great.  Two things make no sense to me: (a) "gold" and (b) "willow".

**Question**: How do I translate 黄金鸡柳咖喱饭?

---

*Edit*: I ordered this dish.  Here's a photo of it:

[image: 黄金鸡柳咖喱饭]

My Chinese friend said that the chicken rings in the back are not really 鸡柳.

Comment: 鸡柳：https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%B8%A1%E6%9F%B3

Comment: "Golden Chicken Curry" does seem to be a thing.

Comment: It is golden brown breaded chicken with yellow curry sauce on rice  (finger size chicken pieces curved into ring shape, it is still 鸡柳 IMO) Plus the golden yellow potato, The word '黄金' (golden) in the dish's name is fitting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

黄金 (huáng jīn) = golden (refers to the color)

鸡柳  (jī liǔ) = chicken fillet (柳 could mean finger size pieces or a steak of chicken,

*牛柳 ='beef fillet'*

咖喱 (gālí) = curry

饭 (fàn) = rice

> 黄金 鸡柳 咖喱饭

1. "golden chicken fillet on curry rice" (if the golden color refer to the fried or baked chicken)
2. "golden curry with chicken fillet on rice" (if the golden color refer to the curry)

I have to see the picture of the dish to decide which it is.

*Since there are  different color of curry , e.g. yellow curry and green curry, 'golden curry' is just another word for "黄咖喱" (yellow curry)*

*To make golden brown colored chicken, the chicken has to be fried/ baked with skin on or breaded)*